# How to use ngIf condition in ionic and angular and display the view accordingly?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ng-if

Currently I working on some home project and learning ionic. I am a php developer moving towards Ionic.

So basically I am using php concept in Ionic project and now I stuck with ngIf condition.

I have a profile page where user info is displayed. 
condition 1 :I want to display add card button if user has not setup their card detail

condition 2: if card detail already the card is setup I want to show edit the card button and hide the add card button.

here is the **HTML** view.

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let c of card  | async">
  <img src="assets/imgs/{{c.cardtype}}.png" width="100%" height="30px">
  <button ion-button (click)="editCard(c)" clear color="core" class="text">Edit Card</button>
</ion-row>
<ion-row >
  <button ion-button (click)="addCard()" clear color="core" class="text">Add Card</button>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" width="100%" height="30px">
</ion-row>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(card | async)?.length > 0; else noCard">
    <ion-row *ngFor="let c of card  | async">
        <img src="assets/imgs/{{c.cardtype}}.png" width="100%" height="30px">
        <button ion-button (click)="editCard(c)" clear color="core" class="text">Edit Card</button>
    </ion-row>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #noCard>
    <ion-row>
      <button ion-button (click)="addCard()" clear color="core" class="text">Add Card</button>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" width="100%" height="30px">
    </ion-row>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: tnx. I will give it try.

Comment: tnx. Works like a charm

Comment: Happy to hear that :)

Comment: It works great when card is an array.But  when card is observable  card.length is not working . What condition shall I put for checking observable.? I am new so this might me a simple mistake. plz help

Comment: Thnx man. you saved my day. Just tried it now and works like a charm for observable.

Comment: Hello can you please help me with this..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614420/how-to-use-ngfor-in-ionic-html-display-according-to-the-count-of-object-and-dete

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it with `ngIfElse`

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let c of card  | async">
    <div *ngIf="condition; else other">
        <button ion-button (click)="addCard()" clear color="core" class="text">Add Card</button>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" width="100%" height="30px">
    </div>
    <ng-template #other>
        <img src="assets/imgs/{{c.cardtype}}.png" width="100%" height="30px">
        <button ion-button (click)="editCard(c)" clear color="core" class="text">Edit Card</button>
    </ng-template>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: tnx for your help.