# How to use ngfor in ionic html display according to the count of object and determining the rest?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

I am a beginner Ionic developer. I am facing some lack logical concept to display the image according to the no of object and determine the rest accordingly. This might be not so clear. SO here the code

What I want is suppose if I get 5 image from database rest 15 should come from for loop.

```
 <ion-grid>
      <ion-row no-padding no-margin>
        <ion-col class="food-item" col-4 *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3..20]" (click)="addFood()">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/250x200" >
              <div class="card-title" >
                <ion-icon name="add-circle" style="zoom: 2.5;" color="core"></ion-icon>
              </div>
          </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

      <ion-row *ngIf="food" no-padding no-margin text-center>
        <ion-col class="food-item" col-4 *ngFor="let f of food | async " class="card-background-page">
            <img [src]="f.image" (click)="editFood(f)" width="250px" height="80px">
            <div class="card-title">{{f.title}}</div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

here I have made two rows -- one for displaying database image and another for adding food. But I want one row with ngfor that will display food images and rest will be placeholder image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in your component wherever you are getting food, once you get response from API do the following:

```
while(food.length < 20) {
    food.push({});
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngIf="food" no-padding no-margin text-center>
        <ion-col class="food-item" col-4 *ngFor="let f of food | async " class="card-background-page">
            <ng-template *ngIf="f.image; else noFood">
                <img [src]="f.image" (click)="editFood(f)" width="250px" height="80px">
                <div class="card-title">{{f.title}}</div>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template #noFood>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/250x200" >
                <div class="card-title" >
                    <ion-icon name="add-circle" style="zoom: 2.5;" color="core"></ion-icon>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: thnx I will give it a try.

Comment: ☻ I am bit confused on how to implement the above code, I  have food provider where I am getting all food data and foodDisplay.ts file to load and parse food to foodDisplay.html view. I will update my question with all the code so my query will be clear.

Comment: In your food provider after getting all food data add the while loop.

Comment: Oh..I got bg with some other things recently. I will give it a try tomorrow and will let you know. Thanks for reminding me..